# Deployment timeout while deploying the ML model in the Azure Container Instance with the azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service

Our code was working fine till yesterday while deploying the ML model on Azure ACI, but facing the deployment timeout or sometimes 400 (Bad response) today.

Is there any issue with microsoft datcenters or there is something else ?

The errors are given below

> "message": "Received bad response from Model Management Service:\nResponse Code: 400\nHeaders: {'Date': 'Thu, 06 Aug 2020 21:05:31 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Request-Context': 'appId=cid-v1:2d2e8e63-272e-4b3c-8598-4ee570a0e70d', 'x-ms-client-request-id': '8aa4dcafb0ec40ef822b55fc4c7a196f', 'x-ms-client-session-id': 'bf2decff-8879-4a9c-bb5f-2fae7034946c', 'api-supported-versions': '1.0, 2018-03-01-preview, 2018-11-19', 'x-request-time': '0.044', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload'}\nContent: b'{"code":"BadRequest","statusCode":400,"message":"The request is invalid.","details":[{"code":"InvalidOverwriteRequest","message":"Invalid overwrite request - cannot update container resource requirements, dns name label, or deployment type. Please delete and redeploy this service."}],"correlation":{"RequestId":"8aa4dcafb0ec40ef822b55fc4c7a196f"}}'"

> "message": "Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy\nOperation ID: 1b6746b3-cdb6-4e0c-a43d-b31b34ac99b2\nMore information can be found using '.get_logs()'\nError:\n{\n "code": "DeploymentTimedOut",\n "statusCode": 504,\n "message": "The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. You can run print(service.state) from the python SDK to retrieve the current state of the webservice."\n}"

Comment: Hi friend, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `InvalidOverwriteRequest-cannot update...`, you already had an existing deployment with same name before the pipeline run.

Are you using the `Azure ML Model Deploy task` from [Machine Learning](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-air-aiagility.vss-services-azureml) task? If so, you need to enable the `OverWrite existing deployment` setting for the deploy task.

[image]